# Drupal Rules, create the SUM of a field decimal values

Tags: 7, rules

I m running a drupal 7 installation and I need to create a special routine for my site.

I have 2 content types -> "Orders" and "Reports".

The "Order" content type has a field with decimal values called "final_value". Any user can create an order with different "final_value" each.

What I need is when a user creates a new report, a rule must trigger and calculate the SUM of all orders she created from the last time she logged in.

Any ideas??

Comment: Why to use rules instead of Calculated Fields?

Answer (score 2):

You could enable PHP filter module (in core package), what will expose a 'run PHP' rule. There you could run some queries. Have a look at [db_select](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) and [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) for how to construct them (there are good advices in the comments as well.).

Proceed with caution though as you are communicating directly against the database. Sanitize the in- and outputs.

If it is only for display purposes, you could achieve a similar effect with Views and aggregation enabled. Enable aggregation in the advanced section. Add the final_value field, and select SUM. This is a much safer approach.

UPDATE

I suppose you are triggering the rule on the save event of the Order-node? In that case the Order is in the $node variable and you could go as follows;

```
$node->field_name = $calculated_value;
node_save($node);
```

Comment: How can I store the calculated value (SUM) from the query in the field of the new "Report" node?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I m afraid the followed structure doesn't work for me:
$node->field_name = $calculated_value;
node_save($node);

Comment: My mistake, the above code works excellent.
Thank you very much